# jQuery array Object from id selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

Original code:

```
var myContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("containerName");

for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    actionRequest(myContainer[i]);
}

function actionRequest(container) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var array = [];
        var object = {//create objects};
        array.push(object);
    }
    container.innerHTML = '';

    $.each(array, function(idx, value) {
        container.innerHTML += '....';
    }
}
```

This works just fine. However as soon as I assign an id to "containerName" instead of a class name:

```
 var myContainer = document.getElementById("containerName");
```

The console.log throws me an error message: "container is undefined".

why?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array while `getElementById` returns a single element.

Comment: javascript `var myContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("containerName");`...... jQuery `var myContainer = $(".containerName");`

Comment: I was thinking that must be the obvious reason. But let's say there is a group of div tags <div id='results-row-content' class='row-content'> , what if I want to reference the 'results-row-content' div tags in my code but not affecting the other row content, how should I go about creating an array in the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes, but `getElementById` returns a single node, so if you want to use that you can just remove the `for` loop around `actionRequest` and call it on the result of `getElementById` directly.

---

Ugly as it is, you can check whether the first element exists to determine whether you should do the loop:

```
if (typeof myContainer[i] === 'undefined') {
    actionRequest(myContainer);
}
else {
    for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        actionRequest(myContainer[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remove the for loop as there are other elements are being manipulated. Please see my comment above, do you have a solution for that>